# MS DNS: Override AD-Stored conditional forwarder

Tags: windows, active-directory, internal-dns, windows-dns

AD DS Setup:

```
Single forest with single domain contoso.com
There are some DNS Servers inside:
DNS-MAIN-01
DNS-SATELLITE-OFFICE-01
DNS-SATELLITE-OFFICE-02
...
DNS-SATELLITE-OFFICE-NN
```

Every DNS server has `Forwarders` that are pointed to local ISP's DNS servers (because local ISP DNS servers provide GeoIP). Internal DNS zones are stored in AD.

I need to create a `conditional forwarder` for some DNS zone held by foreign DNS server `DNS-FOREIGN-01` that is accessible only from `DNS-MAIN-01`.

There is a way to explicitly set non-AD-stored `CF` on each `DNS-SATELLITE-*` server to forward to `DNS-MAIN` server, and on `DNS-MAIN` server - create a `CF` to forward to `DNS-FOREIGN-01` server

Is there any way to avoid explicitly creating `CF` on each `DNS-SATELLITE` and make `CF` AD-Stored, but override AD-Stored `CF` on `DNS-MAIN` server ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can create a conditional forwarder that isn't AD-replicated.
2. No, I can't think of any way you can make it AD-replicated except on one DC.
3. If you're concerned about deploying new DCs and them not having the conditional forwarder, you could create a startup script GPO that checks for the conditional forwarder and then creates it if it's missing, except on your DNS-MAIN server. Just have a line in the script that exits if it's running on DNS-MAIN.

Comment: By the way, the reason I know you can create non-ad-replicated CFs is because a colleague of mine did so by accident and I found it literally *yesterday*. So this is serendipitous.